# In TFS, how can I share source files in different location, in same machine, without sharing the full project

Tags: c#, tfs, location, share, projects

I want to publish some sample code for peoples, for example in CodeProject.
But some source files (.cs files) are part of a large library that I don't want to publish completely.

How I can, in TFS 2012, share source files (.cs files) between 2 different projects (different location). That would let me update source as it would be updated by 2 different users, kind of.

I heard about Workspace but I'm not sure if it is the way to go and how I should do that?

I do not want to branch in order to only manage one version of each source file.

Comment: Do you want the files to always be automatically mirrored, or just be able to keep in sync manually?  A basic branching solution would accomplish the latter.

Comment: I would say automatic mirrored. Like I would be 2 different users. I don't want to manage 2 different version of it.

Comment: Personally, just use GitHub instead, create a public repository and publish your code there. Even Microsoft has moved quite a bit of code to GitHub.

Comment: Thanks for the idea of branching. I will consider that option if this is the only way to go. Actually I copy the code by hands but the new location where source reside is not versionned.

Comment: @Ron Beyer, I already published at GitHub, But although I want to publish at GitHub, I just want to publish partial project sources. I only want to publish required sources (from our libs) for the specific thing I want to show/publish. But I would like to be  able to improve my code from either side: production or demo location.

Comment: Why don't you split up the files into folders and solutions that mirror what you want to achieve instead of publishing to two TFS sources?

Comment: You can always create a separate project and use linked files instead of a full project. You just right click on the project, add existing item, then on the "Add" button drop it down and add as link.

Comment: @Ron Beyer, that would be nice. But when I will zip (if not in GitHub), source file will not be there. Actually is more CodeProject that GitHub.

Comment: @Stephen.vakil, I thought about it: to have smaller project where only sharable code could go. But I would have to split a logical project into many sub projects each time I want to publish. That would make one project split into many smaller ones, which would make referencing them a lots harder, just for publication reason.

Comment: So your scenario is, you have a big project, and once in a while you want to publish some small piece of code to be shared with random others?  Do you know who these people are?  Can you make a custom check-in policy that copies the files to some designated folder each time you check in, or do you not have access to do so?

Comment: @stephen.vakil, I do not share source code with other person directly other that publishing an article (sharing code/ideas). While it is publish, I could make some corrections after but not so often. But while I'm writing the article, I usually improve my code many times. Also it took few weeks to write the article because I still have to continue to work on our regular projects in the meantime... Then both locations could be updated at the same time. Actually I make a copy of code for publication but after I need to do comparison with original code to ensure corrections are propagated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to create a local mapping of the source files to a different workspace folder. Map the folders, don't map the full project.

1. Create a new empty workspace
2. Select those files which you want to share
3. Click *not mapped* beside Local Path, choose a local location to map and get your source files from server.
   [image]

Now you have two copies of your soucre files but with different workspace in your dev machine . When "another person" want to use these files on your machine, he just need to **select the new workspace** to work on it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I began to think that there was no way to do it. I received -1 with no comment to explain it. I also received a vote to close. Usually it happen when peoples don't know the answer and very bad question. I didn't understand what happen and why. Thanks so much. Those who downvote and vote to Close without any comment really doesn't help other users and this website.