# TFS mapping to already existing code by multiple windows users

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, windows-users

I have a solution containing a bunch of projects all under source control that is mapped to a local folder on a PC, but only for a specific windows user, say `UserA`.

Now if I log into Windows under a different user `UserB` I want to be able to use the same code with the same source control, without overwriting any local files (e.g. with the server version. There have been many local changes that haven't been checked in by `UserA`).

However when I open the solution file as `UserB`, I get an error saying:

`The solution appears to be under source control, but its binding information cannot be found. Because it is not possible to recover this missing information automatically, the projects whose bindings are missing will be treated as not under source control`

(this applies to all projects)

The next message box gives me a choice between Temporarily working out of source control or Permanently removing the bindings.

Any attempt to Map the Server folder to the local folder will result in an error stating it's already mapped. Also I said I want to use the existing local code while keeping it under source control (e.g. so `UserB` can check in the changes and any more changes he makes)

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: I don't have good knowledge. But, I guess removing the local mapping and remapping to different directory will give the solution. also, when you are remapping it make sure your server is upto date.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you correctly, you want to use two users coding in same machine with source control.

You  just need to create a local mapping of the source files to a different workspace folder. More detail step for your reference:[In TFS, how can I share source files in different location, in same machine, without sharing the full project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33904048/in-tfs-how-can-i-share-source-files-in-different-location-in-same-machine-wit/33913057#33913057)

Now you have two copies of your soucre files but with different workspace in your dev machine . When "User B" want to use these files on your machine, he just need to select the new workspace to work on it.

However, if you want userB to use the local file mappinged by userA(e.g. with the server version. There have been many local changes that haven't been checked in by UserA) It's impossible and also run counter to the rules of TFS. You must **check in the local changes made by userA first**, then get the lastest version from server for userB.

Answer (score 0):

To share a workspace on one computer between different users, you need to change the advanced permissions of the workspace from Private Workspace to Public Workspace.

This can only be done by the owner of the workspace, which is UserA in your scenario. See the question [How do I choose advanced workspace options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181383.aspx#qa)? for more information.